# Indentkeys Tab behavior

Tags: indentation

I want to have something similar to EMACS tab behavior (described in help indentkeys-format) but I still want to be able to input more tabs if I want.

I thought that adding `!0<Tab>` to indentkeys/cinkeys would do the trick but it totally hijacks the Tab key even when it is not the first character of the line.

I wish I could use Tab as automatic indenter when the line is empty but to use it as a normal Tab key when the line is not empty.

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear: should this only apply in insert mode?

Comment: Yes only in insert mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> getline('.') == '' && line('.') != 1 ? "\<Bs>\<Cr>" : "\<Tab>"
```

It is based on the 'fact' that Vim indent correctly the new lines.

The `<expr>` made that the rhs is evaluated (executed) instead of being taken literally.

`getline('.')` returns the text of the current (`'.'`) line.

If the line is empty the line is deleted and a new line line with auto-indentation is created `<Bs><Cr>`

Otherwise the standard tab is inserted `<Tab>`

Remark: As stated by @Ben it assumes:

```
set backspace^=eol,start
```

For a solution that doesn't rely on that you could do:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> getline('.') == '' && line('.') != 1 ? (line('.') != line('$') ? "\<Esc>\"_ddko" : "\<Esc>\"_ddo") : "\<Tab>"
```

Or in Lua terms:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '<Tab>', 'getline(".") == "" && line(".") != 1 ? (line(".") != line("$") ? "\\<Esc>\\"_ddko" : "\\<Esc>\\"_ddo") : "\\<Tab>"', {expr = true, noremap = true})
```

If you would like the standard behavior after a white line you could do:

```
inoremap <expr> <Tab> getline('.') == '' && line('.') != 1 && getline(line('.') - 1) != '' ? (line('.') != line('$') ? "\<Esc>\"_ddko" : "\<Esc>\"_ddo") : "\<Tab>"
```

Or its Lua variant:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', '<Tab>', 'getline(".") == "" && line(".") != 1 ? (line(".") != line("$") && getline(line(".") - 1) != "" ? "\\<Esc>\\"_ddko" : "\\<Esc>\\"_ddo") : "\\<Tab>"', {expr = true, noremap = true})
```

Here is another version of the same to explain the logic used:

```
function! AdaptIndent()
  if getline('.') != ''
    " The current line is not empty:
    return "\<tab>"
  endif

  if line('.') == 1
    " The current line is the first one:
    return "\<tab>"
  endif

  if getline(line('.') - 1) == ''
    " The previous line is empty:
    return "\<tab>"
  endif

  if line('.') != line('$')
    " The current line is the last one
    " Go to Normal mode: <Esc>
    " Delete the current line into the black hole buffer: "_dd
    " Move to the previous line: k
    " Add a new line with the correct indentation and move to insert mode: o
    return "\<Esc>\"_ddko"
  else
    " Go to Normal mode: <Esc>
    " Delete the current line into the black hole buffer: "_dd
    " Add a new line with the correct indentation and move to insert mode: o
    return "\<Esc>\"_ddo"
  endif
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <Tab> AdaptIndent()
```

Comment: I think this probably relies on the backspace setting including the ability to backspace over the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thanks, is there a Lua translation of this ?

Comment: I'll try to prepare a translation before the end of the day ;-)

Comment: Did you tried the Lua version? It is working for you?

Comment: Yes, just one thing, if the line above is empty it should also act as a normal tab key as there is no need to indent.

Comment: I provided a version that do normal tab if the previous line is empty :-)

Comment: I finally settled with the following: `vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("i", "<Tab>", [[getline(".") == "" && line(".") != 1 && getline(line(".") - 1) != "" ? (line(".") != line("$") ? "<Esc>ddko" : "<Esc>ddo") : "<Tab>"]], {expr = true, noremap = true})`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)